# [conv.integral]/3 in the the latest C++ draft

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I understand the mechanics to convert a `short` into an `unsigned int`. For instance, given a `short y = -1;` and we assign it to an `unsigned int` we'll get the number 4,294,967,295 which is equal to 2^32 -1. If the `short` is equal to -2 and we assign it to an `unsigned int`, we'll get 4,294,967,294 which is equal 2^32 - 2, an so forth.

My problem is to deduce the mechanics explained above from the paragraph [[conv.integral]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#3) in the latest draft:

> Otherwise, the result is the unique value of the destination type that
>   is congruent to the source integer modulo 2^N, where N is the width of
>   the destination type.

I can understand that 4,294,967,295 mod 2^32 = 4,294,967,295 is the unique value of the destination type that is possibly congruent to the value -1 mod 2^32 of the source type (a short). But how do I show that these two numbers are equal?

Comment: `But how do I show that these two numbers are equal?` What two numbers?

Comment: @eerorika 4,294,967,295 == -1 mod 2^32

Comment: Those numbers aren't *equal*. They are *congruent* mod 2^32. You can show if for example by using a calculator.

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate mod for negative number?

Comment: @eerorika That's the definition of congruent. 7 mod 2 is congruent with 5 mod 2, because 7 mod 2 = 1  is equal to 5 mod 2 = 1.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Are you asking for a mathematical proof that -1 and 4,294,967,295 are congruent modulo 4,294,967,296? Surely that is just a simple matter of arithmetic?

Comment: @Brian It's obvious now: -1 mod 2^32 = 2^32 - 1, as - 1 = 2^32*( - 1) + 2^32 -1, where 0 < 2^32 -1 < 2^32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how do I show that [4,294,967,295 and -1] are equal?

Those numbers aren't *equal*. They are *congruent* modulo 2<sup>32</sup> (which equals 4'294'967'296).

To know how to show congruence, let us first take a look at the definition ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)):

> For a positive integer n, two numbers a and b are said to be congruent modulo n, if their difference a − b is an integer multiple of n (that is, if there is an integer k such that a − b = kn)

OK, so let us calculate that difference:

```
d = a − b
d = 4'294'967'295 - (-1)
d = 4'294'967'296
```

Now, let us answer the question, is `d` a multiple of `n`? In other words, does there exist a multiplier `k` that could be multiplied with `d` so that the result is `n`.

Answer: Yes, there is. With `k = 1`, `d * 1` is equal to 4'294'967'296 which is indeed equal to `n`. Therefore we have shown that `-1 ≡ 4'294'967'295 (mod 4'294'967'296`).

Comment: A small correction: `-1 mod 4,294,967,296 ==  4,294,967,295 mod 4,294,967,296`, instead of `-1 ==  4,294,967,295 mod 4,294,957,296`.

Comment: @Alexander the modulo of the congruence is conventionally written on the right side.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Thanks.